# Regex: Change all text content in html page but not change text in attribute

Tags: regex

I have the following words:

```
<a class="logo-home" href="#" title="abc xyz">abc xyz</a>
<img src="#" title="abc xyz" alt="abc xyz"/>
<h1>abc xyz</h1>
<p>blabla... abc xyz ... blabla</p>
```

I want to change string "abc xyz" to `<span style="white-space:nowrap;">abc xyz</span>`
To do that, I use this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/abc xyz/g, "<span style="white-space:nowrap;">abc xyz</span>");
```

But I don't want it change text in title attribute or atl attribute of element. All I want is just change text content in element. I try some regex but the problem still remain. Is Anyone have some advice for me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regex usage isn't actually mandatory here, I would suggest a different approach (a tree exploration for example)

Anyway, to answer your question using regexp (and especially, using the JS flavor of PCRE):
you need to make sure that your "abc xyz" string is followed by a "<" before than a ">", right? Hence, try

`abc xyz(?=[^<>]*<)`

Explanations:

1. `abc xyz` reads chars *abc xyz*
2. `(?=[^<>]*<)` is a lookahead : it does not consumes any char but just make sure that the inner regexp is a success. So we should read chars that aren't < nor >, then a <

Example:

```
'<a class="logo-home" href="#" title="abc xyz">abc xyz</a>\
<img src="#" title="abc xyz" alt="abc xyz"/>\
<h1>abc xyz</h1>\
<p>blabla... abc xyz ... abc xyz ... blabla</p>'
.replace(/abc xyz(?=[^<>]*<)/g, 'hello world')
```

Result is : `<a class="logo-home" href="#" title="abc xyz">hello world</a><img src="#" title="abc xyz" alt="abc xyz"/><h1>hello world</h1><p>blabla... hello world ... hello world ... blabla</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Regex in JavaScript to replace html. Please don't use Regex to parse HTML. [It is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use `DOMParser()` instead.

But if your string is short and structure of HTML is similar like mentioned in question then try this:

```js
var str = `<a class="logo-home" href="#" title="abc xyz">abc xyz</a><img src="#" title="abc xyz" alt="abc xyz"/>
<h1>abc xyz</h1>
<p>blabla... abc xyz ... blabla</p>`;

str = str.replace(/(?<=\<.*?\>.*)(abc\sxyz)(?=.*\<\/\w+\>)/g,'<span style="white-space:nowrap;">$1</span>');

console.log(str);
```